# Problem displaying data from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**Database:**

im trying to get data from a database to display out in a Listview but it wont show up. It force close so I look up at the Logcat and it says that my `populateFrom()` and `bindView()` is null point exception but i dont think thats the problem. I then try to debug them and i notice it came form the `query()` i think. Cuz it got link with the query thats why the method cannot work thus shows error? Maybe.

I try and search useful resources but their query is almost the same as mine. Im abit lost right now. Can anyone help me.? This is just displaying the names of all the `data(food)` in the database. I check and there isnt any error spelling either. ;(

**TestDatabaseMain.java :**

```
public class TestDatabaseMain extends Activity 
{

    private ListViewHelperTest dbListFoodHelper = null;
    private Cursor OurCursor = null;
    private ListFoodAdapter adapter=null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try
        {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listfood);

        //create the database helper
        dbListFoodHelper=new ListViewHelperTest(this);    
        //create the database if user runs the first time
        dbListFoodHelper.createDataBase();

        dbListFoodHelper.openDataBase();

        OurCursor=dbListFoodHelper.getCursor();

        startManagingCursor(OurCursor);

        adapter = new ListFoodAdapter(OurCursor);

        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e ("ERROR","ERROR IN CODE:  " + e.toString());

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ListFoodAdapter extends CursorAdapter
    {
        ListFoodAdapter(Cursor c) 
        {
            super(TestDatabaseMain.this, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) 
        {
            ListFoodHolder holder = (ListFoodHolder)row.getTag();
             holder.populateFrom(c, dbListFoodHelper);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            ListFoodHolder holder = new ListFoodHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            return(row);
        }
    }

    static class ListFoodHolder
    {
        private TextView name = null;

        ListFoodHolder(View displayfood)
        {
            name = (TextView)displayfood.findViewById(R.id.listfood);
        }

        public void populateFrom(Cursor c, ListViewHelperTest r) 
        {       
            //to list out the data from the database
            name.setText(r.getName(c));
        }
    }
```

**ListViewHelperTest.java  :**

```
public class ListViewHelperTest extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{


    //declare constants of the paths
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/sg.edu.tp.iit.mns/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "ListFoodItem";
    private static int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "listfooditem"; 
    private static final String FOOD_TITLE = "FoodItem";
    private static final String FOOD_ID = "_id";


    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private final Context myContext;

    public ListViewHelperTest(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void createDataBase()
    {
        createDB();
    }

    public void createDB()
    {
        boolean dbExist = DBExists();


        if (!dbExist)
        {
            //overwrite the database with the previous database
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            //copy the overwrite
            copyDBFromRecource();

        }
    }

    private boolean DBExists()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try
        {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkDB.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            checkDB.setLockingEnabled(true);
            checkDB.setVersion(1);
        }

        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            Log.e("SqlHelper","database not found");
        }


        if(checkDB != null)
        {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDBFromRecource()
    {
        InputStream myInput=null;

        // Path to the just created empty db

        try
        {
            //Open your local db as the input stream
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            OutputStream myOutput=null;
            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Error("Problem coping folders");
        }   

    }
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String MyPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME ;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(MyPath, null, 
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if (myDataBase != null)
        {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    //important!
    public Cursor getCursor()
    {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

        String[] ColumnReturn = new String[] {FOOD_ID, FOOD_TITLE};

        //search by string pass(*important*)
        Cursor MYCursor = queryBuilder.query(myDataBase, ColumnReturn, null,
                null, null, null, "FoodItem ASC");      
        return MYCursor;
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c)
    {
        return(c.getString(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Cursor.moveToFirst(); on your cursor before doing anything with it.

Comment: u mean inside my getCursor(); ? Sorry but im abit confused.

Comment: Yes, just before you return MYCursor, do a MYCursor.moveToFirst();